# Javascript code is not applying to all the css classes except the first one

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, css

here are three wrapper class but my javascript code is only applying to the first one, i want before and after effect in my image but only first image is responding to that

This is my code

```js
let active = false;

document.querySelector('.scroller').addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
  active = true;
  document.querySelector('.scroller').classList.add('scrolling');
});

document.body.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
  active = false;
  document.querySelector('.scroller').classList.remove('scrolling');
});
document.body.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
  active = false;
  document.querySelector('.scroller').classList.remove('scrolling');
});

document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
  if (!active) return;
  let x = e.pageX;
  x -= document.querySelector('.wrapper').getBoundingClientRect().left;
  scrollIt(x);
});

function scrollIt(x) {
  let transform = Math.max(0, Math.min(x, document.querySelector('.wrapper').offsetWidth));
  document.querySelector('.after').style.width = transform + "px";
  document.querySelector('.scroller').style.left = transform - 25 + "px";
}

scrollIt(150);

document.querySelector('.scroller').addEventListener('touchstart', function () {
  active = true;
  document.querySelector('.scroller').classList.add('scrolling');
});
document.body.addEventListener('touchend', function () {
  active = false;
  document.querySelector('.scroller').classList.remove('scrolling');
});
document.body.addEventListener('touchcancel', function () {
  active = false;
  document.querySelector('.scroller').classList.remove('scrolling');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en' class=''>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head><body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="before">
    <img class="content-image" src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1638/26145024230_06acd55d1b_b.jpg" draggable="false"/>   </div>
    <div class="after">
        <img class="content-image" src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1663/25814974803_d4c55ff708_b.jpg" draggable="false"/>
    </div>
    <div class="scroller">
    <svg class="scroller__thumb" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><polygon points="0 50 37 68 37 32 0 50" style="fill:#fff"/><polygon points="100 50 64 32 64 68 100 50" style="fill:#fff"/></svg>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="before">
      <img class="content-image" src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1638/26145024230_06acd55d1b_b.jpg" draggable="false"/>   </div>
      <div class="after">
          <img class="content-image" src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1663/25814974803_d4c55ff708_b.jpg" draggable="false"/>
      </div>
      <div class="scroller">
      <svg class="scroller__thumb" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><polygon points="0 50 37 68 37 32 0 50" style="fill:#fff"/><polygon points="100 50 64 32 64 68 100 50" style="fill:#fff"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="before">
      <img class="content-image" src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1638/26145024230_06acd55d1b_b.jpg" draggable="false"/>   </div>
      <div class="after">
          <img class="content-image" src="https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1663/25814974803_d4c55ff708_b.jpg" draggable="false"/>
      </div>
      <div class="scroller">
      <svg class="scroller__thumb" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><polygon points="0 50 37 68 37 32 0 50" style="fill:#fff"/><polygon points="100 50 64 32 64 68 100 50" style="fill:#fff"/></svg>
    </div>
  </div>

</body></html>
```

i expected it to apply to all the classes but it only applies to the first one, i tried doing getElementByClassName but it is not working.

Comment: from MDN: `The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.`

Comment: then should i use getElementsByClassName or for loop, to iterate over the arrays of class?

Comment: you should always use getElementByClassName when targeting classes, it is more performant then query selector

Comment: As @Dellirium said, `getElementsByClassName` (don't forget the `s` in elements) and `getElementById` are extremely fast and should be preferred over other selector functions as they are slower. you can do a for loop over the array of elements and add the listeners to each element inside the loop.

Comment: Also remember that the returned value is not an array but an html collection, so take care there

Comment: Also have a look at [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Comment: well, only adding getElementsByClassName did not work, i think, i need to do the for loop.

Comment: would taking this whole code as a function and invoking it through loop work???

Answer (score 0):

The **document.querySelector** function only return one element, if you want to return multiple elements with a CSS selector, you can use **document.querySelectorAll** then use a loop to modify each element.

Example:

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.class');

for(let e=0; e<elements.length; e++) {
  elements[e].classList.remove('classToRemove');
}
```

Comment: Why `querySelectorAll` and not `getElementsByClassName`? it is a lot slower and not needed when searching for a simple class.

Comment: I made the answer to explain why **querySelector** won't work on CSS selectors with multiple results, but if it's only a selector with a class, **getElementsByClassName** would be better of course. @Art3mix